# How to list package download size for those that need to be updated by pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

`pacman -Syu` outputs a list of packages that need be updated. It then prints the *total* update size (i.e. how much data to download).

My question is: is there a way to get the download size for **each** packet that **needs** to be updated? I thought that could be done maybe via `expac` and some text handlin, but I couldn't figure out how.

I was thinking an output print like:

```
package1-name X MB
package2-name X MB
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.

All that's needed is to enable `VerbosePkgLists` in [`pacman.conf`](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.conf.5.html), which according to the documentation:

> Displays name, version and size of target packages formatted as a table for upgrade, sync and remove operations.

This for instance produces

```
Package (183)                    Old Version            New Version            Net Change  Download Size

core/bash                        5.1.004-1              5.1.008-1                0.01 MiB       1.65 MiB
```

Comment: This does not work as of 2022-12-16. If you install ONE package our group  or meta package , yes it shows the details. If you do like OP asked, pacman -Su, NO, it shows total only

Comment: Well, it DOES work , but your terminal needs "unknow width" or in other words, if you terminal is not really really wide , pacman will fall back to not showing the package sizes in detail. A bit weird for debugging

Comment: @CaptainCrunch: I _am_ the OP -- this is self answered. Yes, you do need a bit of space to show all the details which is understandable. Maybe in the future one may choose what info to show in such setting.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
pacman -Qui | awk '/^Name/{name=$3} /^Installed Size/{print $4$5, name}' | sort -h
```

from a slightly modified version of [this command from the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Pacman/Tips_and_tricks&oldid=777583#Individual_packages)